# Divs float results in vertical spaces

Tags: html, css, magento

I've had a problem for a while now. I've been working on new navigation for our webshop, but I keep getting a vertical space between our divs. I've posted a picture here was I marked the divs. These have a `float: right;` added to for them.

[image: Marked divs with black is the problem]

CSS of the marked boxes:

```
#popup5 .col2 .submenuDiv {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 75px;
}
```

I want those marked boxes to stick to each other even if below each other. Right now It looks like they try to make a horizontal structure, but that's not what's wanted. So "Barbering & Hårfjerning" should be pushed below "Dufte". Hope you guys can help me solve this problem :)

Comments tell that there needs to be some javascript to solve this. Any examples of this?

Comment: You have provided `margin-bottom: 10px;` which is causing the gap there.

Comment: actually you cannot achieve this with float or any other CSS features. JS is your only way or a hacky CSS code

Comment: @JoykalInfotechI get that it's providing some gap, but not as much between " "Barbering & Hårfjerning" and "Dufte"

Comment: @TemaniAfif something you've seen an example of somewhere?

Comment: check the duplicate and you will find a lot of examples